# How to write and test dynamic server for Office.js add-in?

Tags: node.js, excel, gulp, ms-office, office-js

**I'm developing an Office.js add-in for Excel, and I'm kind of lost on how to create the server side of the application and test it on localhost.**

I've created the add-in project/structure using Yo Generator, and I'm using gulp to test it on localhost (port:8443). Using this approach, I was able to successfully load my add-in and test the client-side of the same. Also, I've tested a http request to a static json file and it worked fine.

**The issue is that I need to run code on server side for dealing with files and doing some processing, and I simply can't find a way to do that.**

I've already tried to start a localhost server on a different port (port:8000) using the code bellow and node command:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var httpsOptions = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var app = function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(8000);
```

The server started ok, but as my application is running on port:8443, I'm unable to do cross origin requests (which I understand would also not work on a production environment).

I also tried to start add-in server on port:8443 using gulp serve-static command, and then start a server listening on the same port:8443 using node command, but this results on the error bellow:

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at net.js:1379:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)

**May someone please help on how to get this working?**

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have two servers listening on the same port simulateneously. That's why you're getting the Address in Use error.

Second, I am in a similar situation like you and my thinking here was, that the way to go would be writing a server that provides an API (e.g. REST). Then, the javascript code that get's loaded into office (for starters the App.js in your yo office generated project) makes requests to this API.

Comment: Hi @moejoe, thanks for your reply. In this case you are using CORS, right? What I need is everything hosted on the same server. So, I would have a single server to: 1) provide the files for office client to load the add-in; 2) get http requests from the client, execute code and send http responses

Comment: I don't think this is actual CORS as you are using a clearly defined REST API. In this case you could have both things running on the same machine, but they would still be two separate pieces of software.